# How To Pick Desired Image From CSS Sprites In A DIV Background And Position It?

Tags: html, css, image, background, sprite

I have a problem. While designing some codes, I stuck at a position. I want to pick a search icon from a CSS sprites and to keep it to a desired position like shown in below screenshot.

[image]

There are some limitation like I can only edit or add more CSS and I can't edit search Input tag and also can't add more element around Input tag like DIV,SPAN,P,B etc. For this purpose, I wrote a code that is live at **www.jsfiddle.net/JFx9g**.

Is this possible or not? Can you edit this?

Comment: where is that image coming from ?? search image

Comment: In this case you have to arrange icons in sprites vertically. And then code css accordingly.

Comment: @Manjuboyz Image is coming from Sprites...

Comment: @Iqbal There will be a lot of images so cant place them in a straight line.

Comment: @Muhammad, you can use background-position:380px; but it adds up few more pics from sprites, so you need to think technically what should you need to get, is it just the search button or all ??

Comment: @Manjuboyz I didn't get you. I tried more but must have to add one class outside the Input tag. See the DEMO at http://jsfiddle.net/JFx9g/18/

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Then you can use magnifier icon separately. But if you want to include this in sprites, then you have to use two sprite images. One for vertical icons.  Another for rest of the icons.

Comment: You could also use psuedo elements... if it weren't an input! stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field#answer-4660434

Comment: @Iqbal Cant edit Sprite Image...

Comment: @Will I tried that but still have to edit my HTML that I mentioned in Answer. View In below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I think that it is not possible to do it as I asked so I tried myself to do this with as short code as I can and then I got the following one That is also live on **www.jsfiddle.net/JFx9g/18/**

```
<style type="text/css">
.search_text {
    position: relative;
}
.search_text:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -3px;
    right: 7px;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/BX2OXxc.png) -19px -2px no-repeat;
}
.search_text_input {
    height: 24px;
    width: 450px;
}
</style>
<span class="search_text">
<input class="search_text_input" name="q" type="text" value=""/>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (i have also updated the fiddle)

```
<div class='search_input_container'>
    <input class="search_input" name="q" type="text" value=""/>
    <div class='search_glass'></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.search_input_container{
    width:450px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display:table;
}
.search_input{
    border:none;
    padding:5px;
    width:90%;
    outline:none;
    display:table-cell;
}
.search_glass{
    border:none;
    width:18px;
    height:20px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/BX2OXxc.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -20px 0px;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

New Edited JSFIDDLE: **http://jsfiddle.net/JFx9g/10/**

Comment: This is working but I don't want to edit my HTML code or add any new HTML code and you added two DIVs... :(

Comment: No because there are many extra images are in that CSS Sprites... :(
I tried more but must have to add one class outside the Input tag. See the DEMO at http://jsfiddle.net/JFx9g/18/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vikramjakkampudi/W2Cnc/

```
input{
height:30px;
}

 .inputImage {
        background-position: 100% center;
        background-clip: border-box;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-origin: padding-box;
        background-image: url("your image url");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 8px auto;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 93.5% !important;
        padding-right: 5%;
    }
```

add this css and assign `inputImage` class to your input field

Comment: Your code is totally out of world. First try on FIDDLE then share.

Comment: you need to change your image

Comment: This is the real problem. Check my question heading. I have a **CSS Sprites Image** and can't change that one. :(